# Find appropriate solvable coefficients for ODE

Tags: numerical-methods, computational-mathematics

I have the following ordinary differential equation for $y(x)\small x\in [0 \ h]$ where $h>0$

\begin{equation}
Ty''-(P_{0}+\gamma x)[1+y'^{2}]^{\frac{3}{2}} = 0; \quad
y(0) = 0;\quad \frac{1}{y'(0)}=0
\end{equation}

A related question can be found [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2381345/removing-a-singularity-from-a-diferential-equation), and subsequently this related question will called as the "original question" in this query.  The solution to the ode is very similar to calculating the 2D shape of a liqid droplet resting on a solid surface due to surface tension. However, it comes from a geotechnical field problem & not fluid mechanics.

I have solved the above ode in MATLAB using the ode45 suite for given $T$, $\gamma$ and $P_{0}$. Now however, the objective has changed. One needs to find the the appropriate value of $T$, given a constraint that the length of the curve, $L$ plus the ordinate at the end of domain $[0 \ h]$ i.e. $L+y(h)$ is a given constant say $c>0$.

By the way, $h$ can be determined for real solutions by solving for the positive root of the quadratic equation $Ax^2+Bx-2=0$, where $A = \frac{\gamma}{2T}$ and $B=\frac{P_0}{T}$. Moreover, $y'(x) = 0$ at say $x=h_{0}$, provided a similar quadratic equation $Ax^2+Bx-1=0$ is solved for its positive roots. So you can see that given the the coefficients $T$, $\gamma$ and $P_{0}$, the solutions can be numerically evaluated easily.

However,now one needs to find the appropriate coefficients to satisfy a given constraint.

In other words: Given $P_{0}$ and $\gamma$, find appropriate $T$ such that $L+y(h)=c$ for the abovementioned IVP.

Before trying to find an optimal algorithm for calculating $T$, I want to calculate $T$ using a linear search. For this I seed $T$ with a guessed value. This guess is based on the problem's similarity with the case of a liquid droplet as mentioned earlier. For large values of $T$, I assume the shape will be circular. In that case $y(h)=0$ and $h=2r$, where $r$ would be the radius of the circular shape. Hence $h = \frac{2c}{\pi}$. Rearranging the first quadratic equation will solve for the guessed value of $T$, now that $h$ is known.

Now I start with this guessed value of $T$ and keep decreasing it at every iteration to end up with the appropriate value within a specified tolerance. However, there are issues

1. Since ode has a singularity at $x=0$, I specify the IVP to start at $x=0.0001$ instead i.e. $y(0.0001)=0$. Does this detail effect the computation, I don't know. I doesn't seem to be in the  [original question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2381345/removing-a-singularity-from-a-diferential-equation)
2. Since rounding and precision are the evils of computation calculating & specifying exact $h$ is not possible. A bit more than the required $h$ , however, means complex solutions which is not what concerns me. So I specify while numerically integrating in ode45, the problem as the ode equation with domain as $[0.0001 \ h_{modified}]$ with $y(0.0001)=0$ as stated earlier and $h_{modified} = h-100\epsilon$. Note that, $\epsilon$ here is the [machine precision](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eps.html). This procedure works for the [original question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2381345/removing-a-singularity-from-a-diferential-equation). But for linear search, iterations invariably one end up in complex solutions or NaN.
3. The iterations are supposed to be broken when an error term is less than a speciifed tolerance. This error is defined as $|c-(L+y(h_{modified}))|$ where $c$ is known while $L$  and $h_{modified}$ are computed quatities in each iteration.

Frankly, I want to know what am I doing wrong in the linear search that I end up getting complex solutions midway in the iterations. Is there a way to avoid or improve this approach/procedure.

Note 1: 0.0001 is an arbritraily chosen low value close to zero.

Note 2: $100\epsilon$ will guarantee that the rounding error is 100 units in the last place.

Note 3: Instead of choosing $100\epsilon$ one can choose some other value like $10000\epsilon$, but still it doesn't work in the linear search iterations.

Note 4: I computed $\epsilon$ from matlab function [eps](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eps.html). Specifically $\epsilon = $`eps(h)` in matlab syntax.